# What do the numbers on the progress bar mean in spark-shell?

Tags: apache-spark

In my spark-shell, what do entries like the below mean when I execute a function ?

```
[Stage7:===========>                              (14174 + 5) / 62500]
```

Comment: I've changed the example to use more interesting numbers and change the title to make the question easier to find. This takes away a bit from your original question, because this makes it clear that this is a progress bar (which in your case was not at all clear, since it was standing at 0). But I think it is more useful this way overall. If you disagree, feel free to undo my changes! Thanks!

Comment: Sounds fine to me - thanks for that

Comment: Cool question. Wondering why I didn't ask it for a year (duration of my work on Spark)!!

Answer (score 134):

What you get is a `Console Progress Bar`,
`[Stage 7:` shows the stage you are in now, and
`(14174 + 5) / 62500]` is `(numCompletedTasks + numActiveTasks) / totalNumOfTasksInThisStage]`. The progress bar shows `numCompletedTasks` / `totalNumOfTasksInThisStage`.

It will be shown when **both** `spark.ui.showConsoleProgress` is true (by default) **and** log level in `conf/log4j.properties` is `ERROR` or `WARN` (`!log.isInfoEnabled` is true).

Let's see the code in [ConsoleProgressBar.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.0/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ui/ConsoleProgressBar.scala#L73) that shows it out:

```scala
private def show(now: Long, stages: Seq[SparkStageInfo]) {
  val width = TerminalWidth / stages.size
  val bar = stages.map { s =>
    val total = s.numTasks()
    val header = s"[Stage ${s.stageId()}:"
    val tailer = s"(${s.numCompletedTasks()} + ${s.numActiveTasks()}) / $total]"
    val w = width - header.length - tailer.length
    val bar = if (w > 0) {
      val percent = w * s.numCompletedTasks() / total
      (0 until w).map { i =>
        if (i < percent) "=" else if (i == percent) ">" else " "
      }.mkString("")
    } else {
    ""
    }
    header + bar + tailer
  }.mkString("")

  // only refresh if it's changed of after 1 minute (or the ssh connection will be closed
  // after idle some time)
  if (bar != lastProgressBar || now - lastUpdateTime > 60 * 1000L) {
    System.err.print(CR + bar)
    lastUpdateTime = now
  }
  lastProgressBar = bar
}
```

Comment: Great answer!  Here's a link to the pull request that introduced this feature: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/3029.  That page has some interesting design discussions RE: the behavior of this progress bar, especially for multi-stage jobs.

Comment: Thanks! I have been wondering about these numbers for a while

Comment: How many stages are there? Is the total number of stages equal to `totalNumOfTasksInThisStage` ? In other words, once the stage id reaches the `totalNumOfTasksInThisStage` does that mean this job is complete?

Answer (score 51):

Let's assume you see the following (X,A,B,C are always non negative integers):

```
[Stage X:==========>            (A + B) / C]
```

(for example in the question X=7, A=14174, B=5 and C=62500)

Here is what is going on at a high level: Spark breaks the work in stages and tasks in each stage. This progress indicator means that Stage X is comprised of C tasks. During the execution, A and B start at zero and keep changing.  A is always the number of tasks already finished and B is the number of tasks currently executing. For a stage with many tasks (way more than the workers you have) you should expect to see B grow to a number that corresponds to how many workers you have in the cluster, then you should start seeing A increase as tasks complete. Towards the end, as the last few tasks execute, B will start decreasing until it reaches 0, at which point A should equal C, the stage is done, and spark moves to the next stage. C will stay constant during the whole time, remember it is the total number of tasks in the stage and never changes.

The ====> shows the percentage of work done based on what I described above. At the beginning the > will be towards the left and will be moving to the right as tasks are completed.