# Meaning of negative number in PySpark progress bar

Tags: pyspark, progress-bar

The standard pyspark progress bar below [is supposed to indicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46417009/3574579) the number of completed and running tasks (`A` and `B` respectively) out of all `C` tasks scheduled for stage `X`:

```
[Stage X:==========>            (A + B) / C]
```

What am I to make of this progress bar then?

```
[Stage 0:=====> (54288 + -6736) / 65150]
```

More specifically, what is the meaning of a negative number of running tasks?

Comment: If you found the answer to this, I'd appreciate it if you share it here.